# Transforming data retrieved from LINQ (IQueryable) to XML?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml, iqueryable

I presume this is possible? Basically i am receiving using LINQ (LINQ2Entities Entity Framework) data and return it to an IQUERYABLE once i this data i need to transform it to XML in a Memory Stream and a physical file on the hard disk - streamwriter??

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Any help really appreciated

Do i need to use LINQtoXML to accomplish this?

Any examples or tutorials anybody knows of would be great.

Thanks again

**EDIT**

After a little bit of investigation i think i require a XML Serializer for LINQ2Entities / IQueryable??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is probably the best choice. You can use [functional construction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387019.aspx) to create an XML tree in a single statement, like:

```
using (ContactEntities context = new ContactEntities()) {
    XDocument xml = new XDocument(
        new XElement("contacts",
            from contact in context.Contacts
            orderby contact.ContactId
            select new XElement("contact",
                new XAttribute("contactId", contact.ContactId),
                new XElement("firstName", contact.FirstName),
                new XElement("lastName", contact.LastName))));
    xml.Save(yourStream);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is creating the XML using LINQtoXML, how would i transform my data (which exists already in SQL Server) that i have in a IQUERYABLE (from LINQ2ENTITIES) to XML.

Comment: @Martin, you would just project data from the `IQueryable`. I tried to reflect that in my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Entity classes are by default Data Contracts, which means that they can be serialized based on the fields they contain:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a old, but I wanted to show my solution to this problem.

```
public static string CreateXml<T>(IQueryable<T> thisQueryable)
    {
        var thisList = thisQueryable.ToList();
        var xmlResult = "";
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, thisList);
            }
            xmlResult = stringWriter.ToString();
        }
        return xmlResult;
    }
```

Basically this just takes your `IQueryable<T>` and serializes it to `XML` and returns that `XML` as a `string`.

Then you'd basically take that string and....

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(xmlResult);
```

Hope this helps for any future visitors.